# Org Mode Table Create Table from Region shortcut doesn't work

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a list of tab-separated values that I Select using `C-<space> down down down...`

If I use `M-x org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`, it perfectly converts that region to an org-table. However, the shortcut associate with that command `C-c |` doesn't work. It simply adds the `|` character at the end of the region.

I'm in the process of creating 100 or so tables through this process and I'd really want my keyboard binding to work. Unfortunately, this command doesn't disambiguate until I type a lot.

Am i missing something very obvious?

Edit: From a great tip from Andrey I typed `C-h k C-c |` . I can confirm, the key is bound as seen in the following output

```
C-c | runs the command org-table-create-or-convert-from-region, which
is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `org-table.el'.

It is bound to C-c |.
```

Comment: Are you sure that `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region` command is associated with `C-c |`? Does `C-h k C-c |` outputs information about `org-table-create-or-convert-from-region`?

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. I have confirmed this and edited my question -- Key is bound, but it doesn't convert

Comment: Please add a short example of the data that you are working with to your question. Can't reproduce this from your description alone...